# Media Queries in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I'm having problems with my responsive site and Internet Explorer (go figure), and I was wondering if anyone could take a look at the source code in the header of nickpassaro.com and help me figure out why IE9 and IE8 aren't working right. I'm not sure if it's an issue with my css, because some properties that are universal to all three of my stylesheets aren't working (like the background of the header).

I'm using html5shiv as my polyfill, and it's not coming from a local copy on my server. I'm also using normalize.css, which says it works for IE8+

Thank you

Comment: I declared a doctype of html for IE9, and it works now, but IE8 won't accept the shiv

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

If you're looking for more robust CSS3 Media Query support, you might check out http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/. In testing, I've found that script to be noticeably slow when rendering complex responsive designs (both in filesize and performance), but it really does support a lot more media query features than this script. Big hat tip to the authors! :)

Answer (score 0):

there are two different ways for this, either you can use some jquery or JS for IE versions like this

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");
    } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
    } else {
       $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/wide.css"); 
    }
}
```

or you can write different css for different IE versions like this 
for All Versions of IE

```
 <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

for specific versions

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Doing a browser check of if IE will actually do more harm than good down the road.  To make your code future-proof (and current-proof since IE10's interop is amazing), you should use feature detection against specific CSS features you want to use.  You can utilize http://modernizr.com/ to make this easier.  This not only will make the check for older IE versions but also for other non-major browsers as well, making your site look better for even MORE platforms.